# c++ static vector loses elements when in DLL

Tags: c++, vector, dll

So I have a main program that references a DLL (in a separate solution). Here is the design code:

```
//.h of DLL

#ifdef DLL_PREPRO
    #define DLL_LINK __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_LINK __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

enum MyID
{
    //values here....
}

DLL_LINK class MyCustomClass
{
public:
    MyID id;
    LPCTSTR lpszApp;
    LPCTSTR lpszKey;
    LPCTSTR lpszDefault;
    CString& strData;
}

static vector<MyCustomClass> m_customClass; //the vector in question

DLL_LINK void InitTables();

//I have other custom classes that has almost similar structure to this, and with their corresponding vector
//on the .cpp is the implementation of function InitTables() that is called by the EXE side wherein I am doing some processing on the vectors

//.cpp on the EXE side

void AddCustomClass(MyCustomClass c)
{
    (&m_customClass)->push_back(c);
}

//I have another method here who populates the vector by calling AddCustomClass repeatedly
```

My problem is that during debugging, on the exe side I see the vectors getting populated (I do this by 'Add to watch'-ing each vectors), but when I Step Over (F10) to the InitTables function **on the dll side, all the vectors now contains 0 elements**.
BTW, I dragged the cpp file of the dll on to the exe solution to be able to set breakpoints.
Since accessing those vectors with empty elements will throw an error, I temporarily placed a return on top of InitTables() function. Then, when I F10ed again **back to the next line in the exe solution, all vectors now have their elements back**.

So my question is, what is wrong with the design/source code and how should this be corrected? Thank you!

Comment: Are both projects built with exactly the same version of MSVC and exactly the same options?  MSVC does not guarantee C++ ABI compatibility across versions and compilation option differences can also break ABI.

Comment: Both are built in VS2010 pro, but I think there are some differences in the project properties of the two. _Background:_ before was only 1 program - separated a part that is used in other projects as a DLL.

Comment: Background: MSVC has changed the internal layouts of the standard library collections (and other classes) between versions.  So passing a standard library class across modules built with different versions can give exactly the effects you are seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you have used keywork static in header file:

```
static vector<MyCustomClass> m_customClass; //the vector in question
```

In this context static means: this symbol is visible only in current unit.
So each .cpp file which includes this header file have own instance of this global variable! Effectively you can have 10 instances of this variable.

Probably you wanted something like this:

```
extern DLL_LINK vector<MyCustomClass> m_customClass;
```

And in respective .cpp file just add:

```
vector<MyCustomClass> m_customClass;
```

Comment: I tried what you said, but it gave me error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol. From what I understand, it needs to see the cpp file that contains the actual declaration, but in my case is, the error is in the DLL part and it is what's being referenced. How should I work on this?

Comment: sorry forgot about one part, see answer update. extern just says "it is declaration of variable", so definition of it was missing.

Comment: Let me just clarify: am I supposed to extern this DLL in a cpp in the EXE, or do you mean some other cpp inside the DLL? I am quite confused sorry.

Comment: apparently you want to have it in dll. So you have to define this variable in one of cpp of DLL. Disclaimer: I never define global variables (and you also shouldn't) so I'm not sure how this definition should look like. It can look a bit different, for example: `__declspec(dllexport) vector<MyCustomClass> m_customClass;`

Comment: Now that's what I did and the DLL compiled, but now I'm getting unresolved external symbol (for all those vectors) on the exe side. I'm sorry I'm asking for help for every step.

Answer (score 0):

The `static` specifier on a namespace-scope variable gives the variable *internal* linkage. In lay terms, that means that each `.cpp` file will have its own copy of such a variable. Clearly not what you want. If you want the variable to be defined in the DLL but accessed from the EXE, it must actually be `extern` (and exported), not `static`.